# Webpack alias using descriptive filenames does not work in React-app-rewired

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, alias, react-app-rewired

I have set up webpack aliases with react-app-rewired (using `addWebpackAlias` from `customize-cra`) but it **only appears to work** if the filename has the format `filename.tsx` or `filename.ts`.

We use the typical naming convention:

- components eg: `mycomponent.component.tsx`
- redux slices as in the redux docs eg: `configuration.slice.ts`

etc...

Without using webpack aliases, referencing the files works fine, however when adding the aliases, only the files without the `.description.ts` resolve correctly.
VS Code resolves the files correctly, it's only webpack that's not working.

As an example:

`import { Home } from '@pages'` works fine.

`import { Home } from '@pages/home/home.component'` I get a Resolve error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding adding to the moduleFileExtensions configuration the webpack config

```
paths.moduleFileExtensions = [...paths.moduleFileExtensions, 'component.tsx', 'slice.ts', 'api.ts'];
```